# sharey by row in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use pandas dataframe to plot various histograms with function:

```
result_number.plot.hist(subplots=True,legend=False, layout=(6,2), bins=35, figsize=(10,13), sort_columns=False, color="gray")
```

[image: Chart example]

I need to sharey axis in each row by the chart in the left. So in the above image I would like to have on the right side 0/5/10/15 ytickz.

In the second row I would like to have on the right side 0,10,20,30,40 yticks.

I tried following commands, where I put `sharey=True` or `sharey={'row'}` but that returns the same image (see img below), with sharedy on all subplots:

```
result_number.plot.hist(subplots=True,sharey=True, legend=False, layout(6,2), bins=35, figsize=(10,13), sort_columns=False, color="gray")
```

[image]

Minimal dataset to test this issue:

```
,christofides,NN,CHRST_two_opt,NN_two_opt
0,1.0535714285714286,1.1160714285714286,1.0,1.0178571428571428
1,1.0495049504950495,1.1386138613861385,1.0297029702970297,1.0396039603960396
2,1.1217391304347826,1.1478260869565218,1.0260869565217392,1.1043478260869566
3,1.1111111111111112,1.1538461538461537,1.0,1.0854700854700854
4,1.05,1.1416666666666666,1.0166666666666666,1.0333333333333334
5,1.0925925925925926,1.0925925925925926,1.0462962962962963,1.0185185185185186
6,1.0377358490566038,1.2264150943396226,1.0188679245283019,1.2075471698113207
7,1.103448275862069,1.0948275862068966,1.0258620689655173,1.043103448275862
8,1.0769230769230769,1.1623931623931625,1.0427350427350428,1.1025641025641026
9,1.09009009009009,1.2072072072072073,1.027027027027027,1.1081081081081081
10,1.079646017699115,1.336283185840708,1.0265486725663717,1.1327433628318584
11,1.0932203389830508,1.152542372881356,1.0254237288135593,1.076271186440678
12,1.0608695652173914,1.1652173913043478,1.0260869565217392,1.0695652173913044
13,1.0854700854700854,1.1196581196581197,1.0512820512820513,1.017094017094017
14,1.1441441441441442,1.2792792792792793,1.009009009009009,1.1801801801801801
15,1.0789473684210527,1.2456140350877194,1.0526315789473684,1.1491228070175439
16,1.0661157024793388,1.1818181818181819,1.0165289256198347,1.1322314049586777
17,1.0695652173913044,1.1652173913043478,1.008695652173913,1.0956521739130434
18,1.0754716981132075,1.1226415094339623,1.028301886792453,1.0566037735849056
19,1.0442477876106195,1.176991150442478,1.0353982300884956,1.0265486725663717
```

Comment: could you provide a sample dataframe, so that solvers don't have to create one themselves

Comment: sure, what is the preferred format around here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: hopefully I did it right, with the help of the guide. Edited the main post (did head(20) & only first 4 columns to draw first 4 charts)).